# How do I close login request window?

Tags: java, google-chrome, selenium

I am having issues using selenium to close login request.

Site that I am doing some automatic tests on is time to time requesting login.

It is known issue and all you have to do is to close login request and I am trying to write Java script for that. Somewhat this little code of mine doesn't seem to do anything.

```
WebDriver webDriverInstance = handl.browser;
webDriverInstance.switchTo().alert().dismiss(); 
webDriverInstance.switchTo().defaultContent();
```

Any ideas why?

Comment: is there any authentication pop-up?

Comment: like :- https://staging.carfax.si/

Comment: @PapeK24 I have checked your like link. That is a authentication pop up and i like to know, are you trying to close the authentication popup without passing any username/password values?

Comment: Yes sorry i was trying to figure it by myself... it seems to be exactly same pop up

Comment: pop up is just an error issue. It asks for repeated authentication despite you being authenticated already... it just have to be closed because I will not be able to continue my test script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that Webdriver's Alert did not work for me because login request does not rise Javascript alert event. So there was nothing to detect or switch to.

Solved by this piece of code which simply sends ESCAPE key to the browser:

```
Robot robot = new Robot();
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE);
```

Thanks everyone for help.

Answer (score 2):

What you can do is check first if there is pop-up present on not

```
public boolean isAlertPresent() {
    try{
       WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 5);
       wait.until(ExpectedConditions.alertIsPresent());
       return true;
    }
    catch (NoAlertPresentException noAlert) {
      return false;
    }
    catch (TimeoutException timeOutEx){
      return false;
    }
}
```

If it is present then you can accept it like

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);      
Alert alert = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.alertIsPresent());
alert.accept();
```

OR

JavascriptExecutor worked for you. Just take care that you should execute it before clicking the event which invoke alert.

```
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("window.confirm = function(msg) { return true; }");
```

Note :- do not use it after clicking on event which invoke alert confirmation box. Above code by default set the confirmation box as true means you are accepting/click on ok on all confirmation box on that page if invoked. change flag to false if you want to dismiss alert

Hope it will help you :)

Comment: I will check and let you know

Comment: cool .. I have added a JavascriptExecutor code also.. It will accept all your alert if invoked anytime on page.

Comment: Does not seem to work for me. Probably is not an alert because your code waits  till timeout. I may try just sending ESC key or something... Thanks for help tho.